# Data Flow Violation of PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that do ETL between 2 data bases. For get the datas of data base source I use triggers in tables, so my datas are save in new table of agree with type of transaticion: insert, update and delete.

example:

```
Id IdTableSource Transaction
1  1000          'Insert'   
2  1001          'Update'
3  1003          'Delete'
4  1000          'Update'
```

If wacth line number 1 and 4 are abount same IdTableSource. 
In my data flow I use a component for condicional and search if record exists in destination table, but when happens the example above, 2 lines with same record but with type Transaction different I recive the error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY"

My flow is:

- Source
- Conditional (insert, update, delete)
- Lookup for Insert and Update
- If not exists record in my table for Insert ou Update, execute command Insert, else execute command Update.

For first record (number 1 of example) can not find the record in my table, then execute command Insert.

For secund record (number 4 of example) also can not find the record in my table, then execute command Insert (I recive the error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY").

I belive that this happens by be into transaction for SSIS, but I don't know how resolver

[image: Example Data Flow]

Comment: The problem is conceptual, you are moving a historical operation table to a productive one with a primary key on ID. What do you actually need on the destination table? What happens if you also have a delete for that particular ID? You still want that record on the destination table?

Comment: What I actually need is that be done by order, Insert after Update and that the lookup can find the record in my table destination in second execution. If happens record type Delete in my destination table should execute delete (what already does). I don't know if the problem is on lookup, but I can not find any of this.

Comment: For this particular design pattern, you would insert `UPDATE` records into a staging table, then use either an Execute SQL Task to call a stored proc that will handle updating the appropriate records based on what is in the staging table. SSIS isn't actually very good at updating. Your conditional split should be based on the value of the `Transaction` column, I would think.

Comment: @user11890 can't you just replicate the productive table instead of the historical operations? SSIS can't handle ordered operations like this, you should load a copy of the historical table and then use a procedure to impact the changes in order. That, or consider live replication between instances.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I belive that I need other table. Also add image Data Flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not hundred present OK with you solution but if we want to fix the problem that you have I have several things to tell you.

1 : You have Primary key violation because you have insert command two times in your data flow.

[image]

2 : Instead of your data flow I suggest you some things like that.

[image]

Add Three Data Flow task in your control flow.

We transfer all Insert in the first one.

[image]

Then we will transfer all update command. You can improuve your select command for this step by selecting just the last updated for each sourceId command instead of selecting all updated tag.

[image]

The last step is for deleting data.

[image]

But I think you should use this solution instead of yours.

1: Create a temp table in destination database with the same schema that we have in source database.

2 : truncate this table each time.

3 : Bring all Data that from source server to a Temp table in destination database.(All inserted all updated)

4 : Use T/SQL merge command to merge Temp Table and your destination table.

5 : Run a Delete command to delete the rows in destination.

Note: If you have two fields in your source table as (InsertedDate/UppdatedDate)
you do not need trigger in your table for inser and update. you can use those columns with the last transfer date (you have to register it some where each time you are transferring the data)